# use Times new roman font in TOC when using \usepackage{tocstyle} \usetocstyle{allwithdot}

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, tocstyle

I need my TOC all in Times New Roman but my section titles are changed  when using
`\usepackage{tocstyle}` and `\usetocstyle{allwithdot}`

I had to try to use `tocstyle` because my section titles are long and they mess up the alignment in the TOC (they are centered causing many problems).

Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[12pt,times]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{stdclsdv}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot}
```

Below is how I add to the contents, the requirement is that the section title in the TOC be exactly the same as the title in the body. How can I make the font Times New Roman,

```
\begin{center}
\section*{Statistical Estimation of Pharmacokinetic Models with Non-identifiable Parameters}
\end{center}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Statistical Estimation of Pharmacokinetic Models with Non-identifiable Parameters}
```

Comment: Do you need Times only fot the ToC and the sectional unit titles or for your entire document?

Comment: Everything has to be Times new roman. TOC, titles, body. And it all was until I used the tocsytle package to attempt to fix the formatting issues in the TOC.

Answer (score 4):

You have many paths to follow to solve your problem. Here's one with `tocstyle`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
% \usepackage{tgtermes} %% alternative

% all section titles are centered
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\centering}

% all toc entries have leaders
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newtocstyle[standard][leaders]{mytocstyle}{\settocfeature[1]{entryhook}{\normalfont}}
\usetocstyle{mytocstyle}

% No section is numbered
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Statistical Estimation of Pharmacokinetic Models with Non-identifiable Parameters}

\end{document}
```

Note that setting `secnumdepth` to 0 there's no need to repeat the section title in an `\addcontentsline` command.

I've left only the required packages for this solution, add others at will, but *not* `tocloft` along with `tocstyle`.

In order to get Times New Roman as the document font, the `mathptmx` package should be loaded, or `tgtermes` (which provides a clone of Times). The first one is however necessary if you need to set math.

Comment: Hi I need tocloft because I also have a list of figures and a list of tables.

Comment: @Zach So what? The two packages conflict with each other.

Comment: You could also just load font packages, since tgterms gives better text, but will still match with math-mode mathptmx.\usepackage{mathptmx} followed by \usepackage{tgtermes} is working quite nicely for me. (Re:the final line of your answer.)

Comment: Works great if you remove this: `\settocfeature[1]{entryhook}{\normalfont}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use XeLaTeX; in the following example I used `titlesec` to center the section titles:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 

\titleformat{\section}
{\filcenter\normalfont\Large}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Numbered Test Section}

\section*{Statistical Estimation of Pharmacokinetic Models with Non-identifiable Parameters} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Statistical Estimation of Pharmacokinetic Models with Non-identifiable Parameters}

\end{document}
```

A portion of the outcome:

[image]

As a said, run the code with XeLaTeX.

Comment: wow thanks I will check these suggestions out. Thanks!

Comment: Hi again I tried these but they are not changing the font to times new roman in the TOC.

Comment: @Zach: I've updated my answer. Run my example with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Why should XeLaTeX be necessary?

Comment: @egreg: with `mathptmx` Acrobat Reader lists the font used as NimbusRomNo9L and I am not sure that this is exactly Times New Roman as the OP wants. The easiest way to obtain *precisely* Times New Roman seemed to be XeLaTeX.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It's an old recurring question: is a font that is identical to Times the same as Times? Yes, IMO. There are umpteen different versions of "Times New Roman" around and the fact that they share a name doesn't necessarily make them equal to each other (and in fact they aren't). So why should one accept some font that declares itself to be Times and not another one which is quite the same by shape?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think that most people who use Times New Roman really want "Whatever makes my teacher/prof/boss/style department who uses Word's default setting as a style guide happy"